# Adding Images to Inventory Items in NetSuite

Tags: html, netsuite

I have images stored on a CDN, I would like to use the image URL to display the image on the item master. I am using the method below, but I am getting error invalid expression.

1. I create a custom item field called 'External Image URL' of type Hyperlink. Store Value = true.

This field will hold the external image URL. Ex: https://www.gstatic.com/images/brand...r_284x96dp.png

Set field ID to custitem_external_image_url

Then I create a custom item field called 'External Image' of type Inline HTML. Store Value = false.

```
Default value = '<img src="'||{custitem_external_image_url}||'" alt="External Image"">'
```

This will parse the external URL set and display the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just have some unnecessary nested double quotes in there.

You have:

```
Default value = '<img src="'||{custitem_external_image_url}||'" alt="External Image"">'
```

Did you mean:

```
Default value = '<img src="'||{custitem_external_image_url}||'" alt="External Image">'
```

?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Dang tired old eyes. Cheers